# sql count records in from multiple tables using single query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a list of tables for example:

```
mytableA
mytableB
mytableC
```

The tables all have same column (timestamp).

I can do a count on each table individually:

```
select count(*) from mytableA where timestamp = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyymmdd') || '0000';
select count(*) from mytableB where timestamp = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyymmdd') || '0000';
select count(*) from mytableC where timestamp = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyymmdd') || '0000';
```

How can I combine this in one single query? Is there an easy way?

Expected Results:

```
MyTableName     MyCnt
-----------     -----
mytableA        121
mytableB        78
mytableC        2345
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it directly with a query like `where table in (myTableA, myTableB, etc)`
But you can pretify the `union all` solution:

```
select MyTableName, count(*)
FROM(
  select 'myTableA' MyTableName, timestamp from mytableA 
  union all
  select 'myTableB', timestamp  from mytableB  
  union all
  select 'myTableA', timestamp  from mytableC  
)
WHERE timestamp = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyymmdd') || '0000'
GROUP BY MyTableName;
```

Comment: thanks. this is much prettier. I did have to add `GROUP BY MyTableName` to get it to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM   table1
    ) AS tot1,
    (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM   table2
    ) AS tottab2,
    (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM   table3
    ) AS tottab3
```

Comment: that simply elegant solution beats it all IMO

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about Oracle, in SQLserver you can do this as,

```
select (select count(*) from table1) + (select count(*) from table2)
```

**Update:**
or like this,

```
select (select count(*) from table1) ,(select count(*) from table2)
```

OR,

```
(select count(*) from table1) union (select count(*) from table2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 'myTableA' MyTableName, count(*) MyCnt from mytableA where timestamp = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyymmdd') || '0000'
union all
select 'myTableB', count(*) from mytableB where timestamp = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyymmdd') || '0000'
union all
select 'myTableC', count(*) from mytableC where timestamp = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyymmdd') || '0000';
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Oracle 11gR2:

```
select     
  (select count(*) from mytableA where timestamp = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyymmdd') || '0000') tabA,
  (select count(*) from mytableB where timestamp = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyymmdd') || '0000') tabB,
  (select count(*) from mytableC where timestamp = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyymmdd') || '0000') tabC
from dual;
```

Results in:

```
tabA| tabB| tabC
----|-----|-----
 121|   78| 2345
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select 'mytableA' as tablename, count(*) from mytableA where timestamp = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyymmdd') || '0000'
union all
select 'mytableB' as tablename , count(*) from mytableB where timestamp = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyymmdd') || '0000'
union all
select'mytableB' as tablename , count(*) from mytableC where timestamp = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyymmdd') || '0000'
```

Answer (score -3):

How about this?

```
SELECT 
     a, b, c 
FROM 
     (select count(*) from mytableA where timestamp = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyymmdd') || '0000') AS a, 
     (select count(*) from mytableB where timestamp = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyymmdd') || '0000') AS b, 
     (select count(*) from mytableC where timestamp = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyymmdd') || '0000') AS c
```

dunno whether this works or not though :/

Comment: Please do not answer blindly